# child div wider than parent div and overlaping it without body horizontal scrolling, parent width = 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot figure out how to achieve it after hours of searching and trying.

I need the document body to be with no scrolls, neither horizontally nor verically. So the following CSS lines do the trick:

```
body
{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

The markup inside `body` tag is:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left_container"></div>
    <div id="center_container"></div>
    <div id="right_container"></div>    
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
         move to left
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" >
         move to right
    </a>
</div>
```

Additional details:

- `div#footer` height + `div#content` height = 100% . So I am using:

> ```
> #content
> {
>   height: calc( 100% - 60px);
> }
>
> #footer
> {
>   height: 60px;
> }
> ```

- `div#left_container` width + `div#center_container` width = 100% **AND** `div#center_container` width + `div#right_container` width = 100%:

> ```
> #left_container
> {
>    width:300px; 
>    height:100%;
>    float:left;
> }
>
> #right_container
> {
>     width:300px;
>     height:100%;
>     float:left;
> }
>
>
> #center_container
> {
>     width: calc(100% - 300px);
>     height:100%;
>     float:left;
> }
> ```

What I need is that the `div#content` to be of `100% + 300px` without creating a horizontal scroll of the whole page, to be overlapping (physically but not the eyes) the body space and to be "slidable" horizontally using the `jQuery.animate()`, so that it allows showing only `left_container` and `center_container` **OR** `center_container` and `right_container` at a given moment. The anchors in the footer are responsible of triggering the animation between the two situations.

I hope the following figure is illustrating my target:

[image]

Thank you for your usual time and help.

Comment: `overflow:hidden` doesn't work?

Comment: @Paulie_D, thank you for your feedback. As I remember I already tried it to no avail. Maybe it caused the horizontal scroll to appear I am not sure. I will try again

Comment: @Paulie_D, oh! do you mean for body like answers indicate?  not yet I thought you are talking about `div#content`. I will try. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Paulie_D said you can use overflow hidden

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden
}
```

here is a demo hover the id `#content` to see it in action

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden
}

#left_container{
   background: #8DF5F5
}
#center_container
{
    width: calc(100vw - 300px);
    background: #99D9EA
}
#right_container
{
   background: #7092BE; 
}


#content
{
  position:relative;
  width: calc(100% + 300px);
  height: calc( 100% - 60px);
  transition: transform 1s
}
#content:hover{
  transform:translateX(-300px)
}
#left_container,#right_container
{
   width:300px; 
}

#left_container,#right_container,#center_container
{
   height:100%;
   float:left;
}
#footer
{
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="left_container"></div>
    <div id="center_container"></div>
    <div id="right_container"></div>    
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
         move to left
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" >
         move to right
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is an other demo using classList

```js
var content, slideLeft, slideRight;

function addClassToContent(){
 content.classList.add("activated")
}
function removeClassToContent(){
 content.classList.remove("activated")
}
content = document.querySelector("#content");
slideLeft = document.querySelector(".slideLeft");
slideRight = document.querySelector(".slideRight");

slideLeft.addEventListener("click", addClassToContent,false);
slideRight.addEventListener("click", removeClassToContent,false)
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden
}

#left_container{
   background: #8DF5F5
}
#center_container
{
    width: calc(100vw - 300px);
    background: #99D9EA
}
#right_container
{
   background: #7092BE; 
}


#content
{
  position:relative;
  width: calc(100% + 300px);
  height: calc( 100% - 60px);
  transition: transform 1s
}
#content.activated{
  transform:translateX(-300px)
}
#left_container,#right_container
{
   width:300px; 
}

#left_container,#right_container,#center_container
{
   height:100%;
   float:left;
}
#footer
{
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id=content>
    <div id=left_container></div>
    <div id=center_container></div>
    <div id=right_container></div>    
</div>
<div id=footer>
    <a class=slideLeft>
         move to left
    </a>
    <a class=slideRight >
         move to right
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Okey Tambo, I will try your suggestions and feedback. Thanks in advance

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't work for me, it is not positionning the right container alongside the center container (it doesn't float even when inspecting elemets in your answer). Thanks a lot

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers  hover the id `#content` to see it in action

Comment: Now the demo is working as expected, I appreciate a lot your time. Please give me some time to implement it and feedback.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers  you are welcome come back whenever you want

Comment: Thanks. You know what I currently found: changing from `%` to `vw` for `#center_container` is what did the trick (of course with the hidden overflow for body). About setting `position` to `relative` for `#content`, it added nothing (which I think is not mandatory) do you agree?

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers  yes i do agree on that but you still have to add width: calc(100% + 300px); to the id content. check the secound demo usin classList click on left and right to see it in action.

Comment: yeah of course, I already have the given width for `#content` and Ohh thank you very much for the javascript I have right now a working example something to refer to when  writing my own. Thanks a lot. very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if you want slide,

set `#content { width: calc(100% + 300px)}`

and `body {overflow: hidden}`

then animate using jquery

Comment: Ok sir I will for the overflow. For the #content width, I already did. Thanks anyway